# Does the (ning) Async HTTP Client encode query parameters?

Tags: java, asynchttpclient

I'm using the ning Async HTTP client, which sends a request to a downstream server in the following URL format:

`http://{downstream-server}:4080/object/id?query_parameters=a1,a2`

Notice the `,` in the query parameters. My problem is that the HTTP client seems to encode the query parameters before executing the request like so:

`query_parameters=a1%2Ca2`

I know this because the downstream server throws the following exception:

`Invalid query parameter value: a1%2Ca2. Can be a1 or a2`

For some reason, the downstream server does not decode the query parameters. Just before the client executes the request, I check the values of the query parameters in `request.getQueryParameters()`, and there it's still `query_parameters : a1,a2`.

Can I get the HTTP client not to encode the query parameters?

Comment: To be clear, the client I'm talking about is `com.ning.http.client.AsyncHttpClient` version-1.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
setUseRawUrl(true)
```

when configuring the client, like so:

```
new AsyncHttpClient(new AsyncHttpClientConfig.Builder()
    .setUseRawUrl(true)
    .build()
)
```

This should leave the URL untouched.